# Issue with autocorrelation in residuals with auto.arima model

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am quiete new to Seasonal Arima modelling aswell as doing it in R.
From what i have understood there are two ways to get a good model, either by hand or using the "auto.arima" model.

Here i present my data that i am using, its presented in a daily manner over 5 years:
[Data-set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Ev5.png)

We can clearly see that is a seasonality but not much of a trend.
By letting auto.arima handle the model with the following settings:

```
fit <- auto.arima(ny_serie,max.p = 3,max.q = 3,max.P = 3,max.Q = 3,max.d = 2,seasonal = TRUE,
                  max.D = 2,stepwise = TRUE)
```

We get the following model: (1,0,0)X(0,1,0).

And here comes the issue, from what I have learned there is not supposed to be any autocorrelation in the residuals as a claim for a good model.

In the following pictures I have done a box-ljung test(`checkresiduals()`) to be able to test if there is autocorrelation up until lag k.
[Residuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaoTX.png) and [Box-ljung test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS8Gt.png).

Where am I doing something wrong or what can I improve upon?

Best regards.

Comment: If you have daily data there are often environmental or anthropogenic effects that are best modeled with deterministic structure AND possible arima structure. Your data may have one or more trends or one or more level shifts AND most assuredly has anomalous data points. Post your original data and explain what it measures and perhaps I can get more specific.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vRtlega <- original dataset
This data set is of electricity consumption in a specific house in a colder part of my country(2011-2018). Each observation is a daily summarization of measurements from alot of 6 minute interval measurements throughtout the day. 

  What i did with the data set in the post in to remove the two three years because they changed the heating element for the house which lowered the consumption. Also removed the observation that happend on 29th februari on the leap year of 2016.

Comment: Please restore the leap year value because you are distorting day-of-the-week effects

Comment: I restored the leap year observation and re-ran the auto.arima with the same settings. I get the same model with the following residuals. There seem to still be autokorrelations there.

https://imgur.com/a/sziZupy

Comment: Where are the actual values ? Pictures are not of any value ... . What is the beginning date and the ending date, What country is this from ?